# Force usage of native Knockout Templating Engine when not using data-bind

Tags: knockout.js, datatables

I am attempting to use KO with [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/).  I am using [this](https://github.com/CogShift/Knockout.Extensions) project from Github which provides the integration between DataTables and KO. This library does it's own rendering of template rows with the following command:

```
ko.renderTemplate(rowTemplate, bindingContext.createChildContext(data), null, row, "replaceChildren");
```

I want to be able to use KO's native templating engine to render the data, but the page I am using also needs to use jQuery.Templates.  When KO finds a reference to jQuery.Templates on the page it makes it the default template engine, bypassing usage of KO's native engine.

The StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750724/force-native-knockout-templating) discusses how to specify the templating engine to use when using the "template" data-bind syntax.  But how can one specify the template engine when not using data-bind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `ko.setTemplateEngine(new ko.nativeTemplateEngine());` to specify the overall template engine that Knockout uses.  This would get around the fact that Knockout enabled the jQuery Template engine, since it saw that the plugin was available.